# Unity Bullet Doesnt Work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AIEnemy : MonoBehaviour {
   public GameObject bullet;
  public float bulletSpeed = 10;

  public Transform player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {


    }
 void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.tag == "Player")
       {
           // Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, player.position - transform.position);
          RaycastHit2D rhit2d = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, player.position - transform.position, Mathf.Infinity);
          if (rhit2d.collider.tag == "Player")
            {
             var clone = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Rigidbody2D;
            clone.velocity = (player.position - transform.position * bulletSpeed);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my code. When the player stays in the trigger collider it will find the player and fire at it. But my problem is that the bullet doesn't go towards the player it just falls down. I have set the bullet as a trigger so that isn't the problem. (It's a 2D game btw) The project is on Github: https://github.com/Massaxe/2D-AI/

Answer (score 2):

One issue I see right away is related to the fact that the `bullet` is of type `GameObject`. I am going to assume this `GameObject` reference is a prefab you have built and linked to the `AIEnemy` instance. The key thing to note here, is a `GameObject` usually acts as a container for one to many `Component` instances, `Rigidbody2D` being one itself. The following code is what I would use to access the `Rigidbody2D` component:

```
var clone = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
var rigidBody = clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
rigidBody.velocity = (player.position - transform.position * bulletSpeed);
```

As for the math, I would calculate the velocity like so:

```
var vel = player.position - transform.position;
vel.Normalize();
vel *= bulletSpeed;
rigidBody.velocity = vel;
```

What this does, is it calculates the vector between the 2 positions, but, prior to applying the bullet speed, it normalizes the vector (meaning, the vector will have a magnitude of 1, but maintain the appropriate direction). Then, the bullet speed is applied to the normalized vector.

To further expand on this, I would like to note that, if the bullet is falling on its own, there is most likely a 2D gravitational force being applied to the bullet, which may or may not be what you are looking for. In addition, the drag coefficient should also be checked, as if it is any value greater than 0, it will cause the bullet to slow down over time (think of it as friction).

Comment: Instantiate(...) as Rigidbody2D should return the component and not the gameobject, so this is probably not the problem. basically "clone" here is already the Rigidbody2D

Comment: The Instantiate(...) method creates a clone of the first parameter, in this case, the bullet variable. This variable is of type, GameObject. A Rigidbody2D  derives Component, which derives Object. At no point does a Rigidbody2D derive GameObject. That being said, since Instantiate is cloning the bullet variable, and the bullet variable is a GameObject, there is no way it could return a Rigidbody2D. The 'as GameObject' code is merely C# syntax which casts the result of the Instantiate call to the desired type, and returns 'null' if the cast fails.

Comment: my bad, you are absolutely right, but i would suggest taking the bullet prefab as Rigidbody2D then which prevents all the casting

Comment: Good suggestion Tom! My thoughts on that are, a convention should be selected and followed for the most part. For example, in my projects, I have a convention where all prefab references will be linked as GameObject instances. This just makes it easier to differentiate between what is a prefab that I can instantiate, and what is a non-prefab component that was linked at runtime. In the end, its a matter of opinion, but a convention either way will help maintainability and prevent silly mistakes.

Comment: Thanks guys I am going to try it later <3 Youre amazing